# Git clone: index-pack died of signal 25

Tags: git, github, version-control

Following error message is displayed when I try to clone a specific repository. This happened only when cloning that repository.

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 991, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (991/991), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (422/422), done.
error: index-pack died of signal 25, 60.96 MiB | 5.56 MiB/s
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Environment: CentOS Linux 7 x86_64, with around 1.9G memory available.

What I have already tried,

- Cloning the same repo on a different machine; Result: Successful
- Cloning the repo with a lower depth `--depth=1`; Result: Successful

Observations

- The repository seems to have a lots of commits
- Since the cloning worked on another machine, problem should be related to the computer where the problem occurred.

Questions:

1. What does `index-pack died of signal 25` mean? Where can I find documentation for it? Is that related to Git itself or OS?
2. How can I solve it?

I've searched for similar questions which would have had `index-pack died of signal 25` but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Linux signal numbers vary across OSes: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html - on x86, 25 is SIGXFSZ, "file too large". That seems like a likely candidate: someone configured a file size limit for you. Find who set the limit and get it raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), signal 25 is `SIGXFSZ`, which means "File size limit exceeded". [`man 2 setrlimit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) says this:

```
       RLIMIT_FSIZE
              This is the maximum size in bytes of files that the process
              may create.  Attempts to extend a file beyond this limit
              result in delivery of a SIGXFSZ signal.  By default, this sig‐
              nal terminates a process, but a process can catch this signal
              instead, in which case the relevant system call (e.g.,
              write(2), truncate(2)) fails with the error EFBIG.
```

You can use the `ulimit` command to see and possibly change what this limit is.