# Pull branches in chunk(say 100 by 100) due to slow network

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have slow internet connection and I am working on big repository where hundreds of developers commits thousands of changes.

Currently there are 2000 plus commits which I have to pull in my local. However, due to slow network connection, my pull request fails with error "Remote hung up unexpectedly" and I have to try again and again as there is no resume or partial pull.

I am trying to find a way in with which I can pull branches from bitbucket server 100 by 100 instead of pulling 2000 branches at once. Is it possible and feasible ?

I tried many steps mentioned in other questions like:
Increasing buffer size, Switching between SSL and HTTPS and so but it did not help. The problem is slow internet connection and large number of branches to pull. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61407139/7976758

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git clone: index-pack died of signal 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400182/git-clone-index-pack-died-of-signal-25)

Comment: I tried solution provided by @phd and it worked. Thanks.
Just for information that another non - git  approach also worked for me.
It was 
**1.** Take latest updated .git folder from a colleague who had high speed network
**2.** Asked him to compress it and upload it on shared drive which support resume functionality
**3.** Download and extract .git folder and add the repository from local and then prune it and point it to main repository
This way I didn't need to pull whole 1000 pulls in one go. I just had to pull 3-4 newly updated pull request only.